# Reason for Sorting a Hash Table

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, hash, hashtable

I was asked by an employer to sort a hash table. I always thought that the usage of a hash table was in a way non-sort friendly. Am I wrong in thinking this, and if not can you point me to a good VB.Net(Yes Kill me now, but it's an old system) method of sorting a hash table.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this employer have pointy hair?

Comment: It makes me think of Dilbert...

Comment: I found two easy solutions to this from http://blog.larmib.com/2012/sorting-vb-net-hashtable-sorting-resolved/

Answer (score 5):

I have had several cases where I read name-value pairs from a file, need to keep them in the order they were listed in the file, but also need to O(1) lookup times.  A sorted hashtable is how I accomplish both.

For .NET 1.1, use System.Collections.SortedList.  For .NET 2.0+, use System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I like [DocMax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924358/reason-for-sorting-a-hash-table/924376#924376).

Another option:  
Roll your own solution along the lines of what SortedList or SortedDictionary is doing under the hood:

1. put the hash-table keys (or values) into an array
2. sort array
3. iterate over array and output sorted data

(code slightly modified from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0160__Collections/Retrieveallkeyssortanditerate.htm))

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Collections

Public Module modMain
 Public Sub Main()
  Dim myHashTable As New Hashtable

  myHashTable.Add("C", "3")
  myHashTable.Add("A", "1")
  myHashTable.Add("B", "2")

  Dim keys As ICollection = myHashTable.Keys
  Dim keysArray(myHashTable.Count - 1) As String 

  keys.CopyTo(keysArray, 0)
  Array.Sort(keysArray)
  For Each key As String in keysArray
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", key, myHashTable(key))
  Next
 End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Queue:

A queue is used in most OOP like Java, .NET when you need to get what you need to follow the FIFO (first in first out) rule.

A stack is LIFO - last in first out...

```
Dim myQ As Queue(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)) = New Queue(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))

myQ.Enqueue(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(1, "one"))
myQ.Enqueue(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(2, "two"))
myQ.Enqueue(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(3, "three"))

'later on you can retrieve objects by
'myQ.Dequeue
Response.Write("<p>Queue</p>")
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String) In myQ
    Response.Write(kvp.Key & " is " & kvp.Value & "<br>")
Next

Dim ht As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
ht.Add(1, "one")
ht.Add(2, "two")
ht.Add(3, "three")
Response.Write("<p>Hashtable</p>")
For Each kvp As DictionaryEntry In ht
    Response.Write(kvp.Key & " is " & kvp.Value & "<br>")
Next
```